# Eclipse Remote Development, what are the options?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am trying to understand how "remote development" would work in my case:

The Eclipse project I have resides on a Virtual machine on a Sever (the project is not on SVN), so development is done through RDP.

However I want to develop in my local machine (laptop) using a local copy of eclipse, while working on that remote project.

- Not copying the project from the remote machine (just remote access)
- Remote debugging of my java web application project, i.e. debug on my local Firefox or Chrome browser.
- I am developing a GWT web application.

What are the options?

Comment: I'm not positive, but doesn't Eclipse require that all projects reside in the current 'workspace' filesystem?  If so, then maybe you can nominate a workspace location on the remote filesystem, assuming it is mounted to some local path?

Comment: This isn't a comprehensive answer, but I would highly recommend you look into a distributed versioning system (like git). In this scenario, you do work locally, commit, go back to your RDP/server environment, pull changes, continue where you left off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can install an eclipse plugin to archive what you want. I've been using RSE (remote system explorer) http://www.eclipse.org/tm/ and it's been working fairly well. I mainly use it as a more advanced text editor. I've have not using the debugging tool on it so I can't comment on that.